# Does adding a leading caret (^) to a regex expression result in performance gain?

Tags: regex, string, url

In general (across regex implementations), does adding a leading caret (`^`) to a regular expression result in a performance gain or loss?

Assume that the expression will match the same results with or without the leading caret.

In other words, is `^[regexp]` any faster or slower than `[regexp]`, ignoring any differences in what they might match?

For a specific example, let's say we are trying to match URL strings to find any foo.com links.

To do so, we can use the regex `https?://foo\.com/(.*)`.

Would the regex `^https?://foo\.com/(.*)` be any faster?

(For this example, it doesn't matter whether or not we match a string like `https://anysite.com/?http://foo.com/anyothersite.com`.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the general case, but only when the input *doesn't* match.

If the input matches from start of input, adding `^` has no effect and only adds a tiny amount of processing.

Adding `^` will make the expression more specific and therefore the match will fail faster (as soon as possible) rather than having to consume the entire input to assert there's no match.

However, with certain languages/situations, this is not the case. For example, with java's `String#matches()` method, which must match the *entire* input to return `true`, adding `^` may peform a tiny amount worse in all cases, because a `^` is *implied* by the contract, so adding one just adds parsing time and redundancy.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to determine the specific regex implementation used by Firefox web extensions.  Do you happen to know if adding the caret is faster or slower with what they use?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be faster, for the simple reason that it can throw away a non-matching string ideally after having looked at only the very first character. The version without the caret may need to look further.

Think of it like this: what is faster for you as a human?

- Verifying that a book starts with the word „morning“,
- or verifying that a book contains this word anywhere?

Conceptually, for the computer it’s the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think but not sure that `^https?://foo\.com/(.*)` more faster than without ^ because, the regex engine check start of line if it's doesn't match , next line directly.